# Selenium with Scrapy to Scrape the FB pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

This was my spider I can get only the first element result ( Praxy Paris ). I need to get all the data in the most review page. How to get that?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "see"
        start_urls = ['https://www.facebook.com/HRCMallOfAmerica/reviews']
        def __init__(self):
                self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        def parse(self, response):
                self.driver.get(response.url)
                self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("MOST RECENT").click()
                self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)
                elem = self.driver.find_elements_by_id("most_recent_reviews_list")

                for i in elem:
                    x = i.find_element_by_tag_name("strong").text
                    print x
```

Next code tried to get page source of Most recent page but it show only the requested page.

Once process the link by selenium click function I need the html code using python. I have tried but it throws the html code in url of `driver.get(url)`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import urllib,urllib2

f = open('x.html','w')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.facebook.com/HRCMallOfAmerica/reviews"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("MOST RECENT").click()
r=urllib.urlopen(url) // For URL what I have to insert
x=r.read()
print x
```

Comment: does scraping facebook violate its terms of service?

Comment: Then using Facebook API how to get the review , it may ask the page access token . how to get that

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The problem in your code is that the url does not change on clicking the button for the next page. Your code takes in the same url and returns with the same first page.

**Solution**

Keep the button clicking method inside a loop(which should be true till all the pages are covered).

Instead of

```py
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

write

```py
r = urllib2.urlopen(driver.page_source)
```

That should do the work.